# How to prevent JFrame from being decorated

Tags: java, swing, jframe, overriding, look-and-feel

I was working on JRootPaneUI (I am trying to develop a look and feel), and I was making a window with rounded corners. The issue is if I do not use `setShape`, it would leave some artifacts on the corner of the window. However to do so I should set the window to undecorated, and if someone decides to make their window decorated, it would break the UI. So, I was wondering how I could override the JFrame's `setUndecorated` method.

Currently this is the code I came up with.

```
@Override
public void installUI(JComponent component) {
        
    JRootPane rootPane = (JRootPane) component;
    JFrame frame = (JFrame) rootPane.getParent();
    
    // Override instance frame's setUndecorated method here
}
```

There probably is something wrong about using the following method to get the JFrame, so if there is a better method to do so, please consider including it.

Comment: The biggest thing I see wrong in your code fragment is using one character field names.  You haven't provided enough context to your question for anyone to comment.  Are you developing a [look and feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)?

Comment: The answer to the question _How to override a method of an already existing instance_ is: __You cannot do that__. There _might_ be a way to accomplish the goal your body text asks, so I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer, but going by the question asked by the title? Nope.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yea i am trying to work on a look and feel

Comment: @rzwitserloot what would you think is a more appropriate title for my current question?

Comment: Do you know about [`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean))? If an application developer still changes `setUndecorated` explicitly for a specific window, you probably should respect that they want this window not to be look & feel decorated…